# InflateException: error inflating class <unknown>, caused by references to color attributes?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I get the exception below at app startup. The app worked fine with AS Giraffe, the problem first occurred with AS Hedgehog and now as well with AS Iguana.

The layout is a fragment used by the main activities' layout. There are no own classes, it only contains ConstraintLayout, Button, EditText, Spinner and FloatingActionButton.

So how can I trace down the underlying problem? And why does it say "unknown"?

**frag_buttons.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frag_buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorSurface"
    android:minHeight="160dp"
    tools:context=".frag.ButtonsFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTestFunc"
        style="@style/ActionButtons"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:maxWidth="30dp"
        android:maxHeight="15dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="FT"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn6" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtGameEntry"
        android:hint="@string/hintGameNameEnter"
        android:autofillHints="@string/hintGameNameEnter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnTestFuncNext"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnTestFuncNext"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnTestFuncNext" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTestFuncLog"
        style="@style/ActionButtons"
        android:maxWidth="30dp"
        android:maxHeight="16dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="FT Log"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnTestFunc"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnTestFunc" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTestFuncCreateGame"
        style="@style/ActionButtons"
        android:maxWidth="30dp"
        android:maxHeight="16dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="Create Game"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnTestFunc"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnTestFuncLog" />

    <!--        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTestFuncNext"
        style="@style/NbrButtons.Action"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="Next Step"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:cornerRadius="14dp"
        android:tooltipText="Next Step"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnTestFunc"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnTestFunc" />

    <!--        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff" -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTestFuncSkip"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="Skip this Fct."
        style="@style/NbrButtons.Action"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        app:cornerRadius="14dp"
        android:tooltipText="Skip this Check"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnTestFuncNext"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnTestFuncNext" />

    <!--android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTestFuncRun"
        style="@style/NbrButtons.Action"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="Run this Fct."
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:tooltipText="Run check completely"
        app:cornerRadius="14dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnTestFuncSkip"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnTestFuncSkip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTestFuncExit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:text="@string/btnFTExit"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnTestFuncRun"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnTestFuncSkip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btnFTExit" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnTestFuncDiff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnBlock"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnTestFuncNext"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnTestFuncRun" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        style="@style/NbrButtons"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="1"
        app:cornerRadius="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        style="@style/NbrButtons"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="2"
        app:cornerRadius="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        style="@style/NbrButtons"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="3"
        app:cornerRadius="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        style="@style/NbrButtons"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="4"
        app:cornerRadius="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        style="@style/NbrButtons"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="5"
        app:cornerRadius="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        style="@style/NbrButtons"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="6"
        app:cornerRadius="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        style="@style/NbrButtons"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="7"
        app:cornerRadius="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        style="@style/NbrButtons"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="8"
        app:cornerRadius="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        style="@style/NbrButtons"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="9"
        app:cornerRadius="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn7" />

    <!--        app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert" -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUndo"
        style="@style/ActionButtons.Small"
        android:text="@string/btnUndo"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!--        app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClear"
        style="@style/ActionButtons.Small"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/btnClear"
        app:iconGravity="textEnd"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnUndo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBlock"
        style="@style/ActionButtons.Black"
        android:text="@string/btnBlock"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnClear"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCandidates"
        style="@style/NbrButtons.Action"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="@string/btnCandidates"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/btn3" />

    <!--        app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause" -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPause"
        style="@style/ActionButtons.Small"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/btnPause"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnBlock" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLoadTestGame"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:text="Load Test Game"
        style="@style/NbrButtons.Action"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        app:cornerRadius="14dp"
        android:tooltipText="Load Test Game"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnPause"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnTestFuncCreateGame" />

    <!--        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save" -->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabSave"
        style="@style/FloatingActionButtons"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/btnSave"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnBlock"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnBlock"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btnSave" />

    <!--        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" -->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabPlay"
        style="@style/FloatingActionButtons"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/btnPlay"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fabSave"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fabSave"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btnPlay"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Stack dump**:

```
A resource failed to call close. 
Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.myapp.myapp_1, PID: 6191
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in de.myapp.myapp_1:layout/frag_buttons: Binary XML file line #11 in de.myapp.myapp_1:layout/frag_buttons: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in de.myapp.myapp_1:layout/frag_buttons: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:657)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
    at de.myapp.myapp_1.frag.ButtonsFragment.onCreateView(ButtonsFragment.java:55)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
    at de.myapp.myapp_1.act.Myapp1Activity.onStart(Myapp1Activity.java:351)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8018)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 77: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040133 a=-1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:597)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5863)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:697)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:693)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:689)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:587)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:657) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532) 
    at de.myapp.myapp_1.frag.ButtonsFragment.onCreateView(ButtonsFragment.java:55) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251) 
    at de.myapp.myapp_1.act.Myapp1Activity.onStart(Myapp1Activity.java:351) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435) 
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8018) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

The class ButtonsFragment is there, and it compiles without errors. The code snippet causing the exception is simple:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView (@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                              @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate ( R.layout.frag_buttons, container, false) ;
    }
```

And again, it worked perfectly with AS Giraffe. Invalidate Caches and Restart has been done several times.

I removed all references to drawables (as you can see above in frag_buttons.xml). I even replaced "btnTestFuncExit" by a normal Button (which should actually be a ImageButton).

The style used references the following color state list.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="?attr/colorOnSecondary"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="#ff444444"/>
    <item android:color="?attr/colorOnSecondary"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

I found the line `android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList` in the stack dump. I have a suspicion that **references to e.g. `android:color="?attr/colorOnSecondary"`** do not work (probably even in other places than in color state lists): the AS Designer does not display a color related to this attribute.

[Popup displayed by AS Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU6lq.png)

So - how can I trace down (if this is the cause) why the color attributes do not work?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue by myself: the color attribute "colorOnError" (and maybe others) could not be resolved. Now I added all 12 MD color attributes to my own theme, and everything is fine!